# Calculating age of live person vs dead person

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

### **EDIT:**

As someone suggested, I produced a verifiable example. If you take pandas out of it and simply place raw values instead of dataframe values, it works perfectly.

If you bring pandas back into it, as I have below, the program runs and returns 0 for print(true_age).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

data = np.array([['','bornYear','bornMonth', 'bornDay','diedYear','diedMonth','diedDay'],
                ['Record1',1932,8,17,1980,3,22],
                ['Record2',1950,4,12,1980,3,22]])


df = pd.DataFrame(data=data[1:,1:],
                  index=data[1:,0],
                  columns=data[0,1:])

byear = int(df.iloc[1]['bornYear'])
bmonth = int(df.iloc[1]['bornMonth'])
bday = int(df.iloc[1]['bornDay'])
died_year = df.iloc[1]['diedYear']
died_month = df.iloc[1]['diedMonth']
died_day = df.iloc[1]['diedDay']
now_year = datetime.now().year
now_month = datetime.now().month
now_day = datetime.now().day
age_raw = now_year - byear
true_age = 0


if died_year is not None:
    died_year = int(died_year)
    died_month = int(died_month)
    died_day = int(died_day)

    age_raw = float(died_year) - float(byear)

    if bmonth > died_month:
        if bday > died_day:
            true_age = age_raw - 1
        elif bday < died_day:
            true_age = age_raw
    elif bmonth < died_month:
        true_age = age_raw

print(true_age)
```

---

### **ORIGINAL POST:**

So, I've got a pandas dataframe that is the result of a MySQL query that searches for a person's name and then returns some information about them. One such piece of info is their age. The table contains both live and deceased people. I'm trying to make it so that if the individual is deceased, it uses their actual age (at the time of death) rather than what their age would be if they were still alive. If they're still alive, the fields for date of death are empty; if they're dead, those fields of course have values. Here are the relevant variables I've declared:

```
bmonth = int(storage.iloc[0]['birthMonth'])
bday = int(storage.iloc[0]['birthDay'])
byear = int(storage.iloc[0]['birthYear'])
died_year = storage.iloc[0]['deathYear']
died_month = storage.iloc[0]['deathMonth']
died_day = storage.iloc[0]['deathDay']
now_year = datetime.now().year
now_month = datetime.now().month
now_day = datetime.now().day
age_raw = now_year - byear
true_age = 0
```

Now, I've got this designed as nested if statements, but I've gone wrong somewhere. If the person is alive, everything works properly; when I print the age, it outputs the correct age. If the person is deceased however, the age that is printed is always zero. Here is the nested if statements, as well as the relevant print statement:

```
#Here are the nested if statements:

    if died_year is None:   

            if bmonth > now_month:
                    if bday > now_day:
                            true_age = age_raw - 1
                    elif bday < now_day:
                            true_age = age_raw
            elif bmonth < now_month:

                    true_age = age_raw

    elif died_year is not None:

            died_year = int(died_year)
            died_month = int(died_month)
            died_day = int(died_day)

            age_raw = died_year - byear

            if bmonth > died_month:
                    if bday > died_day:
                            true_age = age_raw - 1
                    elif bday < died_day:
                            true_age = age_raw
            elif bmonth < died_month:
                    true_age = age_raw

#And now the print statement:

print("DOB: "+str(bmonth)+"/"+str(bday)+"/"+str(byear)+" ("+str(true_age)+" years old)")
```

Also, I have the following in place so that a date of death is returned in the output if the person is deceased. It is working fine and returning the correct date, so I know the values are all correct:

```
    if died_year is not None:
            print("*DECEASED: "+str(died_month)+"/"+str(died_day)+"/"+str(died_year))
```

**Note** that I didn't convert the variables died_year, died_month, and died_day to integers until the appropriate conditions were met; doing so outside the if statement would have triggered an error because null values can't be passed as int(). I feel like I'm missing something super obvious here, but maybe not. Also, if anyone has a better method for doing all this, I'm always up for learning how to be more efficient.

Comment: Do you think you can produce a [mcve] ?

Comment: Seems like you can do this with `DataFrame.loc` and can avoid loops all together. Converting the dates to `datetime` will make subtraction very simple.

Comment: I would agree with ALollz and also add that a boolean for whether the person is deceased would perhaps be convenient.

Comment: To expand on what @Alessi42 said, I would suggest you check that `died_year` is what you expect it to be. Try `print`ing `died_year`, and making sure it's falsy.

Comment: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` which is to be expected.

Comment: Now it prints `30.0`.

Comment: @Goyo It didn't print 30 for me until I wrapped all of the "died_" variables with int() inside of the if statement. Then I went to the actual production code and tried that fix and it didn't change anything.

Comment: @NathanHinchey it prints out the "died_year" value in both the example and the production code.

Comment: @adrysdale Then your code is not a [MCVE]. Your production code is doing something different or is processing different data or both.

Comment: @Goyo you are correct, but I didn’t discover that until after I posted. Still not sure what the discrepancy was, but the below solution worked so I’m covered for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas has fantastic support for time series, so it's a good idea to leverage the appropriate tools. After we convert our columns to a single Datetime column, we can do time arithmetic on it:

```
# demo dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'birthMonth': [5, 2],
    'birthDay': [4, 24],
    'birthYear': [1924, 1997],
    'deathMonth': [3, None],
    'deathDay': [1, None],
    'deathYear': [2008, None]
})

# convert birth dates to datetimes
birth = pd.to_datetime(df[['birthMonth', 'birthDay', 'birthYear']]
                       .rename(columns={'birthMonth': 'month', 'birthDay': 'day', 'birthYear': 'year'}))
# convert death dates to datetimes
death = pd.to_datetime(df[['deathMonth', 'deathDay', 'deathYear']]
                       .rename(columns={'deathMonth':'month', 'deathDay': 'day', 'deathYear': 'year'}))

# calculate age in days, normalizing 'now' to midnight of today
age = (pd.Timestamp.now().normalize() - birth).where(death.isnull(), other=death-birth)
```

**Edit**: see discussion by @ALollz below regarding timestamp normalization.

Comment: Nice solution. +1. You may consider using `pd.Timestamp.now().normalize()` that way the living people will have a 00:00;00 time part, as there is no information like that for the deceased.

Comment: This looks like a solid solution, I'm going to test it and see what happens.

Comment: That worked exceptionally well. Using your solution, I took "age" and appended a dt.days attribute to it and divided by 365.2422, then output that as an integer. Problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: @ALollz Great suggestion, didn't think of that. Without it, the code above produces different outputs at different times of the day.

Comment: @adrysdale Another thing you can do to convert to years is `age.astype('timedelta64[Y]')`

Comment: I implemented ALollz suggestion from the start, I’m glad he mentioned it. Regarding .astype(), I tried that initially, but it threw an error when I subsequently tried to convert to an integer, which I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Its much easier to convert each of those values into datetime objects then do your if/elif filtering.

```
import datetime
bmonth = int(storage.iloc[0]['birthMonth'])
bday = int(storage.iloc[0]['birthDay'])
byear = int(storage.iloc[0]['birthYear'])

died_year = storage.iloc[0]['deathYear']
died_month = storage.iloc[0]['deathMonth']
died_day = storage.iloc[0]['deathDay']

start = datetime.datetime(month = bmonth, day=bday, year=byear)
end =  datetime.datetime(month=died_month, day=died_day, year=died_year)
(start-end).days#returns the difference between the days
```

You can factor the `datetime.now()` in there as well.

Hope that helps, it will help make your flow better.

Answer (score 0):

#### Edited for the minimal example compatibility

You can define a function which calculates a person's age:

```
from datetime import date 


def calc_age(row):
    bm = row['bornMonth']
    bd = row['bornDay']
    by = row['bornYear']

    dm = row['diedMonth']
    dd = row['diedDay']
    dy = row['diedYear']

    birth_date = date(*[int(i) for i in (by, bm, bd)])  # suppose that all the parameters is not None
    try:
        end_date = date(*[int(i) for i in (dy, dm, dd)])
    except (TypeError, ValueError):  # if death date is None
        end_date = date.today()

    # is birth date after death date or today; if True == 1, else == 0
    is_next_year = ((end_date.month, end_date.day) < (birth_date.month, birth_date.day))
    age = end_date.year - birth_date.year - is_next_year 
    return age
```

Apply this function to your data frame along the rows:

```
df.apply(calc_age, axis=1)
```

and it returns pd.Series with age for all the persons in years if there's no missed data. You can concatenate it to your dataframe:

```
df['personsAge'] = df.apply(calc_age, axis=1)
```

Then add another column with a status and print results:

```
def is_dead(row):
    dm = row['diedMonth']
    dd = row['diedDay']
    dy = row['diedYear']
    try:
        died = date(*[int(i) for i in (dy, dm, dd)])
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

df['is_dead'] = df.apply(is_dead, axis=1)

def print_status(row):
    bm = row['bornMonth']
    bd = row['bornDay']
    by = row['bornYear']

    dm = row['diedMonth']
    dd = row['diedDay']
    dy = row['diedYear']
    age = row['personsAge']

    print("DOB: "+str(bm)+"/"+str(bd)+"/"+str(by)+" ("+str(age)+" years old)")
    if row['is_dead']:
        print("*DECEASED: "+str(dm)+"/"+str(dd)+"/"+str(dy))

df.apply(print_status, axis=1)

stdout:
DOB: 8/17/1932 (47 years old)
*DECEASED: 3/22/1980
DOB: 4/12/1950 (68 years old)
```

If you don't like copy-paste dates selection, replace it by `datetime` approach from [Andrey Portnoy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4557382/andrey-portnoy) solution.